# Want to check if one array has a value of another array, and if it does, change the value of the first array and check it again

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to check if one array has a value of another array, and if it does, the value of the other array should be given a number next to it. If there is a value that matches the value in the other array still, the number should be incremented until it no longer matches a value in the other array. I am struggling with this one. Any help is sincerely appreciated!

For example, "Joe" shows in the below code in both arrays. That means "Joe" in the second array should then be "Joe1". Since "Joe1" is also in the array, the "1" in "Joe1" should then be incremented to "Joe2". Any help is very much appreciated!

```js
var arr = [{name:'Bob',num:0},{name:'Joe',num:0},{name:'Alise',num:0}];
var arr2 = [{name:'Frank',num:0},{name:'Joe',num:0},{name:'Jen',num:0},{name:'Joe1',num:0}];
var cnt = 0

arr.forEach(function(element){
  arr2.forEach(function(element2){
    if(element2.name === element.name){
       while(element2.name + element2.num === element.name){
          element2['num'] = ++cnt;
       }
       if(element2.num != 0){
        element2.name += element2.num
       }   
    }
  })
})

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: `element2['number'] = ++cnt;` looks to be the only place in the logic where `number` is used, rather than `num`

Comment: What is the desired output for this example?

Comment: The code attached to this is sooo confusing, I am not sure what is required to be outputted here.

Comment: element name doesn't seem to be made of name + num but somehow they are compared on a while loop, which doesn't seem right based on the values provided.

Comment: Thanks, updated. @KostasX the desired output is that Joe in arr2 should be updated to Joe2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{name:'Bob',num:0},{name:'Joe',num:0},{name:'Alise',num:0}];
var arr2 = [{name:'Frank',num:0},{name:'Joe',num:0},{name:'Jen',num:0},{name:'Joe1',num:0}];

var arr3;
arr.forEach(e => {
    arr3 = arr2.map(e2 => {
        var name = e2.name.match(/[a-zA-Z]*/)[0]
        if (e.name === name) {
            var number = e2.name.match(/[0-9]+/)
            if (number) {
                e2.name = name + (+number[0] + 1)
            } else {
                e2.name = name + 1
            }
        }
        return e2 
    })
})
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Great solution @Johnny. One problem that I can't seem to make work is the fact that "Joe1" can be in arr1 as well. That means if Joe1 is in arr1 then it can't be in arr2, so the "Joe1" in  arr2 would have to change to Joe2. Your help is much appreciated!